# HTML onload= submit, submiting it nontsop

Tags: php, html

I added function onload to my php website to submit form because when i originally start the page it does not show any table, I must press a search button to load it. Then it works fine.
But when i use onload function it shows the table on web start but it is resubmitting the form nonstop.

```
<body onload="document.search1.submit()">
    <form name="search1" id="search1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        From: <input type="date" id="fdate" name="fdate" value="<?php echo  $date_from; ?>" max="00/00/0000" />
        Until: <input type="date" id="edate" name="edate" value="<?php echo $date_to; ?>" max="00/00/0000" />

        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

this is the submit function.

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST['fdate'])) {
        $date_from = $_POST['fdate'];
    } else {
        $date_from = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
    }
    
    if(!empty($_POST['edate'])) {
        $date_to = $_POST['edate'];
    } else {
        $date_to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
    }

    $fdate = $_POST['fdate'];   
    $edate = $_POST['edate'];   

    $sql = "select 
                date_format(entries.Date,'%d/%M/%Y') AS 'Date',
                user.Name,user.company AS Company,
                user.department AS Department,
                min(time_format(entries.Date,'%H:%i:%s')) AS 'Start Time',
                IF( max(time_format(entries.Date,'%H:%i:%s'))> min(time_format(entries.Date,'%H:%i:%s')), max(time_format(entries.Date,'%H:%i:%s')),'') AS 'Finish Time',
                IF(timediff(max(entries.Date),min(entries.Date)) > '00:00:00', timediff(max(entries.Date),min(entries.Date)), '')  AS 'Work Time' 
                
            from (entries join user on(entries.emp_id = user.emp_id)) 
            where date_format(entries.Date,'%Y-%m-%d') between '".$fdate."' and '".$edate."'
            group by date_format(entries.Date,'%d-%m-%Y'),user.Name 
            order by Date desc";

?>
```

Comment: Where is the `table` that does not appear on page load? What are you trying to display when the page loads - why does it fail? Your sql is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The table consist of results of the $sql querry. It works fine once i press the Search button, but whenever I open the page as new, it does not show the table, only error for the line with: $edate = $_POST['edate']; but it works as i want when i click on Search... Do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `onload="document.search1.submit()"` and tweak the PHP a little the sql should run on first load. The problem, I believe, with the code above is the reliance upon `$_POST` variables being set:

```
$fdate = $_POST['fdate'];   
$edate = $_POST['edate'];
```

If there was no posted data these would be empty and thus the query would not run, so modify that to:

```
    if( !empty( $_POST['fdate'] ) ) {
        $date_from = $_POST['fdate'];
    } else {
        $date_from = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 days'));
    }
    
    if(!empty($_POST['edate'])) {
        $date_to = $_POST['edate'];
    } else {
        $date_to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 days'));
    }

    $fdate = $date_from;     # use the value determined by the `IF` logic
    $edate = $date_to;       # use the value determined by the `IF` logic
```

You can also make your SQL easier to read if you use `aliases` for table names

```
$sql = "select 
            date_format( e.`Date`, '%d/%M/%Y' ) AS `Date`,
            u.`Name`,
            u.`company` AS `Company`,
            u.`department` AS `Department`,
            min( time_format( e.`Date`,'%H:%i:%s' ) ) AS `Start Time`,
            IF( max( time_format( e.`Date`,'%H:%i:%s' ) ) > min( time_format( e.`Date`,'%H:%i:%s' ) ), max( time_format( e.`Date`,'%H:%i:%s' ) ),'') AS `Finish Time`,
            IF( timediff( max( e.`Date`), min( e.`Date` ) ) > '00:00:00', timediff( max( e.`Date`), min( e.`Date` ) ), '')  AS `Work Time`
            
        from entries e 
        join user u on e.`emp_id` = u.`emp_id`
        
        where date_format( e.`Date`,'%Y-%m-%d') between '{$fdate}' and '{$edate}'
        group by date_format( e.`Date`,'%d-%m-%Y'), u.`Name` 
        order by `Date` desc";
```

That said it is still vulneable to SQL injection so you migfht wish to use a `prepared statement` instead - perhaps like this:

```
$sql = "select 
            date_format( e.`Date`, '%d/%M/%Y' ) AS `Date`,
            u.`Name`,
            u.`company` AS `Company`,
            u.`department` AS `Department`,
            min( time_format( e.`Date`, '%H:%i:%s' ) ) AS `Start Time`,
            IF( max( time_format( e.`Date`, '%H:%i:%s' ) ) > min( time_format( e.`Date`,'%H:%i:%s' ) ), max( time_format( e.`Date`,'%H:%i:%s' ) ),'') AS `Finish Time`,
            IF( timediff( max( e.`Date`), min( e.`Date` ) ) > '00:00:00', timediff( max( e.`Date`), min( e.`Date` ) ), '')  AS `Work Time`
            
        from entries e 
        join user u on e.`emp_id` = u.`emp_id`
        
        where date_format( e.`Date`,'%Y-%m-%d') between ? and ?
        group by date_format( e.`Date`,'%d-%m-%Y'), u.`Name` 
        order by `Date` desc";

$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$fdate,$edate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($date,$name,$company,$department,$start,$finish,$worktime);
while( $stmt->fetch() ){
    echo $date,$name,$company,$department,$start,$finish,$worktime;#format output as apporpriate!
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: When i run  this, it will always turn off my SQL service on server.

Comment: I used, in the last piece, `$conn` as the db variable as it is unknown what you used. Perhaps that is the issue. What errors are you seeing in the error logs? Presumably you are using `mysqli`?

Comment: @ProffesorAbronsius yes mysqli, not sure what is cousing the crash, might be problem with buffer?Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=65537
thread_count=7
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 20288 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Comment: does the other version without the `prepared statement` run ok ?

Comment: the first version works, the one with $_Post Statements.